# Unity freezing after leaving fullscreen app/game

Tags: unity

Sometimes, exiting a fullscreen app/game will make Unity freeze. I know the computer isn't freezing because I can switch to a virtual terminal and use `sudo service lightdm restart` to restart Unity. This doesn't happen with all my games, only some. For example, Dolphin emulator. If I fullscreen it, it's still working fine, but as soon as I press `alt+enter` to leave or `escape` to quit it, it'll go back to Unity and freeze immediately after (if I press `escape`, the exit confirmation dialog sometimes appears partially). Ikaruga through wine does the same thing if I exit fullscreen or if I exit the game. I've been looking for an answer for a while now, and I can't find anyone with the same problem.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on a Macbook Pro.

Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2435M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4

Graphics: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile